# How to store the result of Dymanic pivot into a temp table without specifying column names for a table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I was trying to do dynamic columns pivot for a table. 
I was able to do that, thanks to the explanation provided here 
([SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query))

```
create table pivottest (Columnname varchar(100), value varchar(100)) ; 
insert into pivottest values ('Age', '25'), 
('Email', 'Rob@gmail.com'), 
('Phone', '888888888'), 
('Name', 'Rob'), 
('Age', '20'), 
('Email', 'Bob@gmail.com'), 
('Phone', '999999999'), 
('Name', 'Bob'), 
('Age', '20'), 
('Name', 'Ben'), 
(null, null)
```

I am doing the same way based on the answers provided in the link?

```
select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by columnname order by value) Rownum  
into #temp from pivottest 

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.Columnname) 
        FROM #temp c
        FOR XML PATH(''))  
    ,1,1,'')


set @query = 'SELECT   '+@cols+'  from 
        (
            select Columnname, Rownum 
                , value
                from #temp
       ) x
        pivot 
        (
             max(Value)
            for Columnname in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p '

Execute @query
```

I get the result which I desire for pivot section, now I wanted to store the data into some temp table and refer that in the same session as it gives me error saying object does not exist.

I can do select * into some physical table in this way. I can refer the physical table every time. But I wanted to do in #temp table

```
set @query = 'SELECT   '+@cols+' into  dynamicpivotdata from 
        (
            select Columnname, Rownum 
                , value
                from #temp
       ) x
        pivot 
        (
             max(Value)
            for Columnname in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p '


execute(@query) 
select * from  dynamicpivotdata
```

Also, I can get the results from Temp table but I have to create the table first with all the columns required, and then I can refer it in this way. But I wanted to do like Select * into  for temp table like I did for physical table without specifying the column names. Is there any way to store the data in temp table?

```
 create table #temp5 (Age int ,
 Email varchar(100),
 Name varchar(100),
 Phone varchar(15))

 set @query = 'SELECT   '+@cols+'   from 
        (
            select Columnname, Rownum 
                , value
                from #temp
       ) x
        pivot 
        (
             max(Value)
            for Columnname in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p '


insert into #temp5  execute(@query) 
select * from #temp5
```

My Final Output which I get from #temp5 and dynamicpivotdata looks like this. It would be helpful if I get the same output from select * into #temp table option if possible.

```
Age   Email         Name    Phone
20  Bob@gmail.com   Ben     888888888
20  Rob@gmail.com   Bob     999999999
25  NULL            Rob     NULL
```

Comment: How your final output looks like. Please represent it.

Comment: @SurajKumar Please check the final output which I have added.

Comment: Please check the update answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like I could make use of global temporary table in this way to get my desired results.

```
 set @query = 'SELECT   '+@cols+' into  ##temp1 from 
    (
        select Columnname, Rownum 
            , value
            from #temp
   ) x
    pivot 
    (
         max(Value)
        for Columnname in (' + @cols + ')
    ) p '


execute(@query) 
select * from  ##temp1    


Age   Email         Name    Phone
20  Bob@gmail.com   Ben     888888888
20  Rob@gmail.com   Bob     999999999
25  NULL            Rob     NULL
```